# Cuda parallel reduction tutorial shows race condition

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I am trying out the parallel reduction [tutorial by Mark Harris](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).
I tested for Reduction #1-#4 and they were fine, but when I get to Reduction #5: Unroll the Last Warp,
I get race conditions when testing the code with cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck.
What am I missing?

Here is the code I tested with (test.cu):

```cs
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define BD 128

__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int* sdata, int tid)
{
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
}
__global__ void reduce5(int *g_idata, int *g_odata)
{
    __shared__ int sdata[BD];
    // each thread loads one element from global to shared mem
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockDim.x*2) + threadIdx.x;
    sdata[tid] = g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockDim.x];
    __syncthreads();
    // do reduction in shared mem
    for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>32; s>>=1) {
        if (tid < s) {
            sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
    // write result for this block to global mem
    if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}

int main(){

    int n=10000;
    int *hin;
    hin = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) hin[i]=1;

    int *din;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&din,n*sizeof(int));

    int GD = (n+BD-1)/BD;

    int *dou;
    cudaMalloc(&dou,GD*sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(din, hin, n*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    GD = (GD+1)/2; 
    reduce5<<<GD, BD>>>(din, dou);

    int hou[GD];
    for (int i=0;i<GD;i++) hou[i]=0;

    cudaMemcpy(&hou, dou, GD*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    int ans=0;
    for (int i=0;i<GD;i++) {
        ans+=hou[i];
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Running

```
cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ./a.out
```

The output show several warnings like:

```
WARN: Race reported between Write access at 0x00000458 in test.cu:10:warpReduce(int volatile *, int)
=========     and Read access at 0x00000530 in test.cu:11:warpReduce(int volatile *, int) [3744 hazards]
```

All the warnings come from race conditions that happened at each line in `warpReduce`.

When I put `__syncthreads();` after each line in `warpReduce`, the error disappears. But in the tutorial, it says that if s<32, we don't need to __syncthreads() because there is only one warp left and the instructions are SIMD synchronous within a warp.

So I am wondering why the tutorial says we don't need syncthreads(), but I can only make the race condition go away if I put syncthreads(). Is there something wrong with my code? Or is the race condition not really a problem?

Comment: The tutorial to which you are referring was written 14 years ago. A lot has changed in 14 years

Comment: I hope this will help: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cooperative-groups/  (more modern approach to reduction)

Comment: "But in the tutorial, it says that if s<32, we don't need to __syncthreads() because there is only one warp left and the instructions are SIMD synchronous within a warp."  That doesn't mean that a potential race won't be flagged.  Both ideas can be true at the same time.

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907772/cuda-min-warp-reduction-produces-race-condition)